# Error: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE on AWS S3 pre signed upload url

Tags: amazon-s3

When we upload to a presigned url in AWS chrome gives the error `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` and fails to upload

Answer (score 5):

The error `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` indicates that the url is using an untrusted certificate. This can happen if there is a `.` in your bucket name e.g. `foo.bar`. Amazon makes the upload url `foo.bar.s3.amazonaws.com` which does not match the certificate `*.s3.amazonaws.com`. This is how wildcard certificates work.

## Fix

Change the bucket name to remove any `.`s e.g. `foo-bar`. The upload url will become like `foo-bar.s3.amazonaws.com` and that will match the s3 certificate `*.s3.amazon.com`.

Comment: You're a little bit confused on one point: `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` does not *necessarily* mean there's a self-signed certificate.  It means the certificate is untrusted -- maybe because it is signed by an untrusted CA (including self-signed) -- but it also can mean **the domain name does not match the cert**.  A `*` wildcard in a cert is not allowed to match a dot, therefore `foo.bar.example.com` does not match a cert for `*.example.com` yet `foo-bar.example.com` does.  S3 does not return a different cert, and this issue is a limitation in the design of SSL certs, not a limitation of S3.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks a ton. Definitely helps clear my confusion. Updated the answer accordingly.